# Summing cells that have themselves sum formulas in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, sum

When trying to use the =SUM formula in Microsoft Excel 2013 for summing cells that have themselves =SUM formulas, the result is 0

Comment: Can you explain this a little better? I've just created some mock data, summed two columns of data, then summed the two summed cells and it worked perfectly. Maybe a screen shot of the data will help too.

Comment: Can you detail the exact formulas you are using?

Comment: Here is the printscreen http://s3.postimg.org/5wd4z1i1v/5435.png

Comment: Have you tried pressing F9, in case auto-recalc is disabled for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem : sum works for raw data and for summed sells. E.G. there are raw data in A1-A9 and in B1-B9. If A10 sums "his" column and B10 too, you can put a =sum(a10:b10) in C10. So far so good.
My problem comes with more complicated formulas in EG A10. Suppose that I say in A10 : =if(A3>0;sum(A1:A9;0), it will not sum up anymore in C10.
I found out that the raw data are not that raw... They need to be converted to numbers. Then it works again.
Hope this helps.